# How to set href value inside $.each ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with downloading file inside a thread. My problem is that I cannot assign the file name inside the href and download attribute so when I try to download it it display no file. I tried replacing the href with specific data and it works.

Please help me assign the name of the file I get inside href and download attrib.

Here is my javascript:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value)
{
    var message = value.message;
    var cnt = value.count;
    var n = message.includes('.jpg') || message.includes('.png') ||
            message.includes('.jpeg')|| message.includes('.pdf') || message.includes('.csv') || 
            message.includes('.docx') || message.includes('.xlsx');
    message = value.message;

    $('#divv').append('<a href="uploads/{{"'+value.message+'"}}" 
                       download="{{"'+value.message+'"}}" style="font-weight: bold;"
                       class="bsi">' +
                      '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>'+
                      "  "+value.message+'</a>'+ 
                      '<i class="bsi_date">'+value.dateReplied+" "+ value.username+'</i>');
    getUserFullName(cnt);
}); //each
```

Comment: What‘s with the {{ … }} around the value? I doubt you actually want `uploads/{{foo}}`

Comment: I already try that way but still not working

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle/jsbin?

Comment: Then give us a proper [mcve] so that we can see what is actually going on. We have no idea right now what your `value` object contains, so impossible to tell as of now.

Comment: Im sorry for vague explanation. I am curently working on downloading a file inside a message thread. My only problem is I cannot add the file name of the file Im going to download inside the href attribute. The name of the file is in value.message. Can you please help me put the value inside href link

Comment: `'<a href="uploads/"'+value.message+'" download="'+value.message+'"' ...`

Comment: Omggggg thank  you very muchh @04FS Its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use this function

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#?").attr("href", "https://whatyouwant/jquery/");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="https://www.whatyouwant.com" id="?">whatyouwant.com</a></p>

<button>Change href Value</button>

<p>Mouse over the link (or click on it) to see that the value of the href attribute has changed.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks